# Confidence Interval for the Dispersion parameter of negbin distribution

Tags: generalized-linear-model, negative-binomial-distribution, overdispersion

Can anybody show me, how to find a CI to Dispersion parameter of negbin distribution in R?

Iknow how to calculate the point estimate but I do not know how to find the confidence interval

so, what is the IC for this example: 
[enter link description here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10985/dispersion-parameter-of-negbin-distribution?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

The `theta` parameter is not part of the main model parameters in `glm.nb` (as extracted by `coef()`) but it is treated as a nuisance parameter. However, the fitted model object contains the parameter estimate (`$theta`) and its standard error (`$SE.theta`). So you can easily employ a Wald confidence interval based on the asymptotic normal distribution (essentially +/- two standard errors).

```
library("MASS")
a <- glm.nb(Days ~ Eth + Sex, data = quine)
a$theta + qnorm(c(0.025, 0.975)) * a$SE.theta
## [1] 0.8872956 1.4555238
```